# store mysql prepare query result in array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to store mysqli prepare statement result in array. So i can use json encode method and use it in other page.

At the moment it is returning only 1 row. I checked the query and query is working fine.

It seems like i am doing some silly mistake but can't figured it out.

```
$start = 2;
$limit = 2;
$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, email, description, mobile, post_date FROM users order by id DESC limit ?,?");
$result ->bind_param("ii", $start, $limit);
$result->execute();
$result->store_result(); 
$data = array();
$total = $result->num_rows;
if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
    $result->bind_result($name, $email, $description, $mobile, $post_date);


    while ($result->fetch()){
        $data['name'] = $name;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['description'] = $description;
        $data['mobile'] = $mobile;   
        $post_date = $post_date;
        $data['newDate'] = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($post_date));
        //echo $name;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you just do yours queries and push the results into an array ?

Comment: You overwrite on every iteration. `$data['name']` will only have the last name, as will all other indexes.

Comment: @chris85 Please explain. I didn't get you

Comment: If row 1 is `john` and row 2 is `chris` and only 2 rows are returned `$data['name']` would be `chris`. `john` is overwritten on second pass. Simple demo: https://eval.in/546810

Comment: @chris85 Then what do i need to do? any advise.

Comment: I don't know how you are using that array but something like `$data['name'][]` would store all the name reuslts. That builds array dynamically, it becomes dimensional though.

Comment: You'd need to use a `foreach ($results as $var)` here, not a `while`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Life saver. Any example would be very helpful.

Comment: This may help http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php yet you'd need to do some modifications if you can. You could also try `foreach($result->fetch() as $data)` but not 100% sure that will work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. I am checking the link. Will let you know.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I tested your code but using my own quick query and I think it's because of how you setup your query. If you were to remove the `limit ?,?` and its associated code and bind on an email address and/or an id instead, you will see that it will now echo the rest of your table. You can also try adding a GROUP BY. You may also have to remove `$data = array();`.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Another option I used in another script that I wrote (some time ago), is something like this `while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ $var = " Some text " . $row->column_name; }` - So that may work for you. That will give you a lot more freedom and use a lot less code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. I am already using this method.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Right on. So is the question solved? What would you like to do, delete the question? or did my comment solve it?

Comment: I am thinking to put answer in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array();
while ($result->fetch()){
                                $data[] = array(
                                    "name" => $name,
                                    "email" => $email,
                                    "description" => $description,
                                    "mobile" => $mobile,
                                    "newDate" => date("d-M-Y", strtotime($post_date))
                                );
                                }
```

Thanks to Fred. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result->execute();
$data = $result->get_result()->fetch_all(); 
$total = count($data);
```